# API gate way mapping with multiple API- Best practices

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have 2  development API's and deployed AWS.I need to map this api API gateway for getting outsides AWS. And also need separate keys for Security. Whether i need to create 2 api gateway ?What is the best practice in this scenario .Also expecting multiple version of API's in future.

I need to know
How many API gateway need to create
How many stages need to create if it only one.
In API gateway apikey used to mapp the stages of the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Key points to remember:

- Access/Throttle/Limits are controlled by usage plan and api key at stage level not at individual resources/methods within that api.
- Who can call what api is usually controlled by authorizer, whether it is IAM Auth or a custom Authorizer.
- Stages are usually used for multiple environments. we can't have some resources/methods is one stage but not in other stage.

With these in mind, hopefully we can make decisions. My Typical approach is this.

- Have one Api Gateway for One Business Function Ex: order-api , for CRUD on Order, Ship order, etc.
- Each Api with 2 stages, live & staging. Publish first to staging, if everything looks good publish to Live.
- Create one or more usage plans. Create 1 Api Key per client, even if they use same usage plan.

Comment: If I have multiple API's with different business function(Different source code, environment and apikey ).What is the recommended approach?

Comment: I would choose two different APIs.